# Helping with coding in a python program, on determining the body-mass index of a collection

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

"writing a Python program to determine the body-mass index of a collection of six individuals. Your program should include a list of six names. Using a for loop, it should successively prompt the user for the height in inches and weight in pounds of each individual. Each prompt should include the name of the individual whose height and weight is to be input. It should call a function that accepts the height and weight as parameters and returns the body mass index for that individual using the formula weight × × 703 / height2. That body mass index should then be appended to an array. Using a second loop it should traverse the array of body mass indices and call another function that accepts the body mass index as a parameter and returns whether the individual is underweight, normal weight or overweight. The number of individuals in each category should be counted and the number in each of those categories should be displayed. You should decide on the names of the six individuals and the thresholds used for categorization."

I started the program but I need help with coding a list for each persons BMI and whether or not they are underweight, normal weight, or over weight with their name in the output.

```
def bmi(height,weight):#function to calculate BMI
    return ((weight*703)/(height**2))
def bmi_category(bmi): #function to determine under weight, normal weight, over weight
    if (bmi<18.5):
        return 0
    if(bmi>=18.5 and bmi<25):
        return 1
    if(bmi>=25):
        return 2

#prompt user to input their name
people=["Sarah","Mary","Joe","Allie","Tristan","Jack"]
bmi_list=[] #this will turn people into a list
#start the variables at 0 
underweight=0
normalweight=0
overweight=0
#promt the user for their height in inches
for i in range(6):
    print("Name:",people[i])
    height=float(input("Enter your height in inches:"))
    weight=float(input("Enter your weight in pounds:"))
    bmi_list.append(bmi(height,weight))
```

Comment: Unless you use tkinter, the editor/IDE should make no difference in the code you write.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't fully understand what you needed but I think this solves your problem (probably not the best way)

```py
def bmi(height,weight):#function to calculate BMI
    return ((weight*703)/(height**2))
def bmi_category(bmi): #function to determine under weight, normal weight, over weight
    if (bmi<18.5):
        return 'underweight'
    if(bmi>=18.5 and bmi<25):
        return 'normalweight'
    if(bmi>=25):
        return 'overweight'

#prompt user to input their name
people=["Sarah","Mary","Joe","Allie","Tristan","Jack"]
bmi_list=[] #this will turn people into a list
#start the variables at 0 
underweight=0
normalweight=0
overweight=0
#promt the user for their height in inches
for i in range(6):
    print("Name:",people[i])
    height=float(input("Enter your height in inches:"))
    weight=float(input("Enter your weight in pounds:"))
    bmi_list.append(bmi(height,weight))


bmi_count = {'underweight':0, 'normalweight':0, 'overweight':0}
results = {}
for j in range(6):
    category = bmi_category(bmi_list[j])
    print(people[j], category)
    bmi_count[category] = bmi_count[category] + 1

print(bmi_count)
```